# Use Nuance ASR with proxy server

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, nuance

I am working with a Pepper and NAOqi 2.5.10.7.

I have a simple application, that uses Nuance remote ASR and replies the understood text.
Everything works fine with a direct internet connection.

When I connect Pepper to our company network, Nuance remote ASR does not work anymore.

Our companys network uses a proxyserver for internet connections.
We configured a application proxy for Pepper and allowed connection to

```
*.nuancemobility.net
```

I could test Pepper successfully connect to nuancemobility.net in ssh via

```
wget nuancemobility.net.
```

But when I run my Choregraph Application Nuance remote ASR does not work.

Since all other connections work fine, it seems as the nuance module (NuanceVoconEngine?) does not use the proxy settings that I set in the os environment variables. (for all users: nao and root)

```
export http_proxy=http://companyProxyServer:port
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$http_proxy
export FTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

I also set the proxy server in the "Network Settings" on Peppers "Robot Web Page"

What can i do to make Nuance remote ASR work although the internet connection uses a proxy server?

Are there additional Environment variables that Nuance remote ASR (NuanceVoconEngine?) needs to use my proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to set a proxy for nuance remote. This is an issue with the system (all versions are impacted).